how can I set up CSS classes feature for the Highlightr-Plugin?
I am asking about the Highlightr-Plugin, it mentions instead of declaring everything inline, you can store the CSS settings in CSS class:

Version 1.1.2 adds the ability to choose between inline CSS and CSS classes. This will create a new stylesheet that will how all of your highlight colors. Each class is named hltr-${highlight_title_here} and are generated from the titles by which you have named your highlights

I would much prefer this instead of having inline CSS all over my markdown file but I dont know how to set this up and the plug in does not go into detail on how to do this.
I am thinking, I need to create a .css file but place it where?
I have a background in Python/cpp. Web dev is not my area at all. If anyone has any ideas on how to do this, I would appreciate it.
windows11, latest obsidian and highlightr.

from the description, it sounds like if you enable the feature, it will create the css files for you, and you just edit them. It also sounds like the application manages multiple sets of styles. its not clear whether you can just drop a file in and have it be used.
